# How to use SQL*plus from standard user in Windows Vista to run sql query to Oracle10g on my server?

Tags: windows, oracle-10g, sqlplus

i have a bach file it contain:

```
@echo off
sqlplus x/y@z @run.sql
```

for execute this code correctly i have to execute this file from administrator user from my client, for some reason i need to run this file from a standard user without administrator privilege and without any password request.

when i research about my problem, i understood sqlplus can't be run without administrator privilege.

How to connect to SQL*plus from standard user in Windows Vista to Oracle10g on my server?

Answer (score -1):

I didn't find how to run sqlplus from standard user but JJ. answer in this question help me to find alternative way.

I just use [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553) to run sqlplus in my server.